# What will happen when timestamp (rowversion) overflow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm wonder if it's safe to compare the values of timestamp in a table to get the newly updated/inserted rows. (e.g. [SQL Server RowVersion/Timestamp - Comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470807/sql-server-rowversion-timestamp-comparisons)).

What will happen if timestamp reaches the maximum value of binary(8) in a very very large/frequently updating database?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It won't.

If you do a million updates a second, every second, the timestamp will wrap around in about 585000 years.

Comment: It won't happen. But still, just by mere curiosity, does SQL Server handle this in some way?

Comment: @guillegr123: I looked for a while now, and I can't find any documentation for that. I found a claim that it would actually wrap around to zero in an answer, but there is no reference to any documentation to back it up. http://stackoverflow.com/a/547782/69083